# Which Linux distributions support full disk encryption (including /boot)?

Tags: system-installation, boot-loader, distribution-choice, disk-encryption

Recently I came across many Linux distributions. Before that I've been always using OpenSUSE so some things apparently were quite obvious to me - for example that it's possible and quite easy to set up full disk encryption or arbitrary, custom mount options on installer level. However it seems that actually such option is really exotic and apart from Arch Linux (where it's hard to call it "supported by installer"), probably Gentoo and OpenSUSE I couldn't find any distribution that allows you to encrypt whole disk (including /boot).

Just to avoid confusion - I'm talking about setup where first stage of GRUB asks for password before even showing GRUB menu to unlock initrd, then initrd asks for the same password again to load kernel and other stuff. In OpenSUSE installer it's performed automatically in case /boot is placed on encrypted LVM. However Debian, RedHat, CentOS, Ubuntu, Mint and probably all distros using similar installers claim it's incorrect configuration and refuse to install OS.

Are there any other non-specialized (means those strictly privacy oriented distributions like Tails or Whonix don't really count) distributions apart from mentioned 3 that support such installation scheme?

> EDIT: In response to @henriquehbr to be 100% clear on what do I mean by **full disk** encryption:
>
> [image]
>
> There's no separate /boot partition. System asks for password twice: In GRUB:
>   [image]
>
> And after GRUB:
>   [image]
>   [image]
>
> In the end there's only 1 partition which is encrypted LVM:
>   [image]
>
> **However**
>
> What is referred to as "encrypted LVM" in all other installers I know:
>   [image]
>
> Is configuration with separate /boot partition.
>   [image]
>
> Trying to remove /boot partition results in following errors on Debian and Ubuntu:
>   [image]
>   [image]

Sorry for a lot of pictures but I wanted to make it 100% clear.

Comment: I didn't use either. I created encrypted LVM and then btrfs partition on that LV, mount under `/` and when clicked [ok] intaller told me that `/boot` has to be unencrypted :C

Comment: And lol mount options choice is given from predefined positions so there's no `space_cache` or `autodefrag` or `compress` options specific to btrfs...

Comment: `/boot` encryption is unusual and mostly pointless. If you really must have it, you can do it post-install. It should not narrow your distro choices.

Comment: @frostschutz You mean that `/boot` should be stored on external read-only medium? Well yes. But it's significantly less convenient as well. However while this time it didn't disqualify Debian - lack of custom mount flags did. Without `compress=zlib` flag it failed to install on 2gb HDD.

Comment: @Lapsio I'm trying to figure out the same problem. Did you ever determine whether it is or is not possible to encrypt /boot along with everything else?

Comment: @RobertDodier I didn't find any other distros that can do that. But I didn't check too many of them. However a lot of distros base on the same installers so it's quite easy to reject most of distros right away if they reuse CentOS/Ubuntu/Debian installers

Answer (score 1):

I think all of the big name distributions do. Debian, Fedora, Ubuntu, openSUSE and so on. they may not advertise it as much as Ubuntu and Mint do, but the option is almost always there in the disk partitioning section of the installer.

---

> **EDIT: In reply to @Lapsio, i googled about this, and found that Ubuntu and Mint still
>   support the full disk encryption during installation**
>
> ### Ubuntu 16.04
>
> [image]
>
> ### Mint 17.X
>
> [image]

Comment: The problem is Ubu and Mint don't support it either. I can only see it working in OpenSUSE installer. (and Arch and Gentoo allows you to do such thing as well but they don't really have conventional installer so I'm not sure if it counts). Ubu and Mint don't even allow you to install OS if disk is smaller than 8gb lmao.

Comment: Answer updated with proof of concept!

Comment: It doesn't encrypt `/boot`. Hence it's not _full disk_ encryption. It encrypts root partition but leaves `/boot` unencrypted. So initrd is not encrypted. Encrypting `/boot` requires additional steps and modifications to bootloader setup so it's less trivial.

Comment: updated question

Comment: @Lapsio It's true that /boot is not encrypted doing it this way but does it really matter. All you are worried about is your data especially in your home folder. I suppose if you were to encrypt your boot as well, you will be logging with your secret keys twice; Once for the boot and once for the rest of the hardrive.

Answer (score -2):

The old 32bit Linux Distros complied with your wishes... Something happened when 64bit Linux Distros released and that feature was forgotten.  I would like it reintroduced.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/426327)